# What does a non-significant intercept mean in a meta-regression using rma.mv ? Does it indicate problems? If so how to solve them?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, intercept, metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis using the metafor package in R. More specifically I use a random effects model applying the rma.mv function. When I run my meta-regression with moderators, I always get an insignificant intercept. As I rarely see this in published meta-analyses, I was wondering whether something is wrong with my model? My effect sizes are standardized mean differences (Cohen's d) and I have continuous as well as categorical moderators. I also tried mean-centering the continuous moderators. This reduces the p-value of the intercept substantially, but it is still not signficant. I would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: The intercept is the estimated $y$ value when all the moderators are zero. Why would you be concerned if this turns out to be close to zero?

Comment: I have read that this is rarely the case in meta-analyses (and cannot find one meta-analysis in my field that reports an insignificant intercept). Some sources indicate that it might be due to model misspecification. However, other sources report that it must not be a problem at all. I am simply concerned that it might be a bigger problem that I oversee right now.

Comment: What scientific question demands that you have a non-zero intercept?

Comment: Probably non...I was just concerned that something is wrong with my model that I may overlook here due to missing statistical knowledge as this is rarely seen. On the other hand is the model quite robust and the other estimates seem logical. Although I do not have any highly significant predictors.